# Существуют ли архивы задачек с возможностью сдачи на ruby?

Tags: ruby

Существуют ли архивы задачек с возможностью сдачи на ruby, по типу Тимуса, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот интересный пост на хабре, который как раз по Вашей теме http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/ruby/123271/

Answer (score 1):

codeforces.ru